# space between text and border bottom

Tags: html, css

How do I create distance between the text and the border below the text as shown in the image attached using sass/css?

I want the distance to be 5px and the font-size of the text to be 15px.

I tried doing

```
.selected {
  color: #284660;
}
.selected:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #284660;
}
```

but that created a border that was too wide.

[image]

Comment: Include the relevant HTML please. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Your problem is with the width of the border? Do you need a border with the same width of the text?

Comment: what exectly you need?

Comment: top:0 bottom:0 takes the height of the container , so if you have 100px height, border-bottom will be really far ... width:100%; again strecth the border to entire width of parent ... Give us yout html and css that reproduce your issue, then you may get some efficient help, here we are wasting time guessing where you went wrong. With some guess for html, that's about we can see from your code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGdrER (&) removed on first selector of course cause as is , won't work

Answer (score 3):

I feel couple of things which can be improved in the above snippet.

1. You may not need psuedo element for desired effect
2. You should not use absolute positioning for that , in case you want to use psuedo element

In any case you can try this out.

```
&.selected {
color: #284660;
border-bottom: 2px solid #284660;
padding-bottom:10px ; // this should give you some spacing.
}
```

Comment: Won't work if `&` is a non-positioned `block;` element, or a `inline-block;` or positioned `block` element with a declared `width` or `min-width` longer than the text, as the bar will still be longer than the text.

Comment: @abluejelly Please see this plunkr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9TS1fj0HEKWi77cBWsT7?p=preview)plunker code

Comment: That is not the code you posted in your answer, nor does that demonstrate what my comment was pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative

{

bottom: -5px;

}

Comment: probleme we have no idea of parent's height nor padding ... -5px will put it 10px further from text :)

Comment: also will not fix  the bar being "longer" than the text (which is caused by the `&` targeting a non-`inline` element.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the complete lack of knowledge of your DOM profile or what element the `&` refers to, if you just slap a border and padding on an `inline` element, you'll have the effect you want.

No need to play with pseudoelements.

```
<span style="padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:2px solid black;">Some Text</span>
```

Obviously, you should put that styling info in the css file, I merely inlined it for the example.

---

Oh and next time, please include sample HTML with your sample CSS. Only reason I even bothered was because the solution was as simple as "What is `padding` for 15, Trebek?"